# How setup a rule in ufw?

Tags: ufw

I have a vps with two ip addresses. The nics are Eth0 and Eth0:1
How do I setup a rule that allow all traffic on Eth0:1 to only use ports 5001-5999

Regards
Anders Yuran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Block interface:

   ```
   sudo ufw insert 1 deny in on {interface-here} from any to any
   ```
2. Allow desired ports:

   ```
   sudo ufw insert 1 allow in on {interface-here} from any to any port 5001:5999/tcp
   sudo ufw insert 1 allow in on {interface-here} from any to any port 5001:5999/udp
   ```

Comment: Ok thanks! So the first rule make all other traffic dropped? This i exactly what I want

Comment: You're welcome, you can accept the answer by clicking on gray tick if you think it was helpful to you ;)